# Update/ replace value of extended property using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have around 500 columns and I want to update their extended property value using T-SQL. Basically value has | (pipe) in it and I want to replace all | with  `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`.

For testing I'm trying to update one value using below code and I'm getting this error

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.

```
UPDATE p
SET p.value = REPLACE(p.value, '|', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
FROM sys.tables AS tbl
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns
        ON clmns.object_id = tbl.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p
        ON p.major_id = tbl.object_id
           AND p.minor_id = clmns.column_id
           AND p.class = 1
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id) = 'dbo'
      AND tbl.name = 'ACXM_HHLD'
      AND clmns.name = 'Business_Owner';
```

Comment: You can't `UPDATE` the `sys` objects; if you need to change the values of the extended properties, you need to use the appropriate system procedures

Comment: A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=change+value+of+extended+property+sql+server) (at least for me) gives you the 2 Special Procedures you need to update and add extended properties.

Comment: @Larnu, That's how added values. But now I wan to replace | to new line.

Comment: For me, the first result is how to up0date them with `sp_updateextendedproperty `.

Comment: I cannot do this with system proc.
`EXEC sp_updateextendedpropertyN 'MS_Description',
                                'Employee ID must be unique.' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ANSP' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'ANPS',
                                 N'Schema',
                                 dbo,
                                 N'Table',
                                 ACXM_HHLD,
                                 N'Column',
                                 Business_Owner;`

Comment: You can't pass expressions... Just like any procedure. Even `EXEC dbo.MyProc 1 + 2;` would fail. You would have to assign it to a variable first: `DECLARE @I int = 1+2; EXEC dbo.MyProc @i;`

Comment: @Larnu, That's the issue. How can I replace | to New line in extended property value.

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64704373/update-replace-value-of-extended-property-using-t-sql#comment114406184_64704373).

Comment: @Larnu, I have 500 columns. It' going to be very tedious.

Comment: It would well be; dynamic SQL may well help you achieve the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was trickier as I thought with NVARCHAR(MAX) that cannot be converted into SQL_VARIANT and stored procedures that don't accept inline CAST expressions...

But this here should do the trick, replacing all `|` in all column descriptions through `CrLf`.

```
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'DECLARE @Text AS NVARCHAR(4000);' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'DECLARE @Variant AS SQL_VARIANT;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

WITH Description ([Schema], [Table], [Column], [Text]) AS (
  SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), tbl.name, clmns.name, CAST(p.value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM sys.tables AS tbl
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS clmns ON clmns.object_id = tbl.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS p ON p.major_id = tbl.object_id AND p.minor_id = clmns.column_id AND p.Name = 'MS_Description' AND p.class = 1
)

SELECT @TSQL = @TSQL + 
  N'SET @Text = ''' + REPLACE(REPLACE([Text], '''', ''''''), '|', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) + ''';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
  N'SET @Variant = @Text;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
  N'EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty N''MS_Description'', @Variant, N''SCHEMA'', ''' + REPLACE([Schema], '''', '''''') + ''', N''TABLE'', ''' + REPLACE([Table], '''', '''''') + ''', N''COLUMN'', ''' + REPLACE([Column], '''', '''''') + '''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM Description

EXEC sp_executesql @TSQL
```

Comment: what is the desired output?  Why is a cast required